# Rolling Product in PANDAS over 30-day time window

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am trying to get data ready for a financial event analysis and want to calculate the buy-and-hold abnormal return (BHAR). For a test data set I have three events (noted by *event_id*), and for each event I have 272 rows, going from t-252 days to t+20 days (noted by the variable *time*). For each day I also have the stock's return data (*ret*) as well as the expected return (*Exp_Ret*), which was calculated using a market model. Here's a sample of the data:

```
index   event_id    time    ret       vwretd    Exp_Ret
0       0           -252    0.02905   0.02498   nan
1       0           -251    0.01146   -0.00191  nan
2       0           -250    0.01553   0.00562   nan
...
250     0           -2      -0.00378  0.00028   -0.00027
251     0           -1      0.01329   0.00426   0.00479
252     0            0      -0.01723  -0.00875  -0.01173
271     0            19     0.01335   0.01150   0.01398
272     0            20     0.00722   -0.00579  -0.00797
273     1           -252    0.01687   0.00928   nan
274     1           -251    -0.00615  -0.01103  nan
```

And here's the issue. I would like to calculate the following *BHAR* formula for each day:

[image]

So, using the above formula as an example, if I would like to calculate the 10-day buy-and-hold abnormal return,I would have to calculate (1+ret_t=0)x(1+ret_t=1)...x(1+ret_t=10), then do the same with the expected return, (1+Exp_Ret_t=0)x(1+Exp_Ret_t=1)...x(1+Exp_Ret_t=10), then substract the latter from the former.

I have made some progress using *rolling_apply* but it doesn't solve all my problems:

```
df['part1'] = pd.rolling_apply(df['ret'], 10, lambda x : (1+x).prod())
```

This seems to correctly implement the left-side of the BHAR equation in that it will add in the correct product -- though it will enter the value two rows down (which can be solved by shifting). One problem, though, is that there are three different 'groups' in the dataframe (3 events), and if the window were to go forward more than 30 days it might start using products from the next event. I have tried to implement a *groupby* with *rolling_apply* but keep getting error: *TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed*

```
df.groupby('event_id').apply(pd.rolling_apply(df['ret'], 10, lambda x : (1+x).prod()))
```

I am sure I am missing something basic here so any help would be appreciated. I might just need to approach it from a different angle. Here's one thought: In the end, what I am most interested in is getting the 30-day and 60-day buy-and-hold abnormal returns starting at time=0. So, maybe it is easier to select each event at time=0 and then calculate the 30-day product going forward? I'm not sure how I could best approach that.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited so that final values of BHAR are included in the main DataFrame.

```
BHAR = pd.Series()

def bhar(arr):
    return np.cumprod(arr+1)[-1]

grouped = df.groupby('event_id')
    for name, group in grouped:
        BHAR = BHAR.append(pd.rolling_apply(group['ret'],10,bhar) -
                           pd.rolling_apply(group['Exp_Ret'],10,bhar))

df['BHAR'] = BHAR
```

You can then slice the DataFrame using `df[df['time']>=0]` such that you get only the required part.

You can obviously collapse the loop in one line using `.apply()` on the group, but I like it this way. Shorter lines to read = better readability.

Comment: Thanks for that -- looks promising. However, I'm getting the following error using either suggestion: "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars."

Comment: Where? In `return np.cumprod(arr+1)`?

Comment: I don't see that in the Traceback anywhere -- looks like it's here: ----> 2     group['BHAR'] = pd.rolling_apply(group['ret'],10,bhar) - pd.rolling_apply(group['Exp_Ret'],10,bhar)

Comment: Try `return np.cumprod(np.asarray(arr)+1)`. See the very bottom of the Traceback for the last function called.

Comment: Found it. Edited the answer. `np.cumprod` returns an array. I assumed it would only return the final cumulative product.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to get the right answer when I put *print group* in the for loop, but I am getting this error: /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__main__.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. It is because we are setting `group['BHAR'] = something`. If we take a copy of group like `'temp = group.copy()` and work on `temp` the warning will not be raised. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks again, but I think I'm missing something. After I run the code the 'BHAR' column is not there. Do I need to do something else to make it persist?  Do I just need to change the line from *group['BHAR']* to *df['BHAR']*?

Comment: Eh no. You were not missing anything. That is the expected behavior. Changes to the group are not to be propagated to the parent (they should never be). Check out the edited answer, I think it will solve all of your questions. Mark my answer as the accepted answer if it does.

Comment: Thanks for all the help with this! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Create sample data.
np.random.seed(0)
VOL = .3
df = pd.DataFrame({'event_id': [0] * 273 + [1] * 273 + [2] * 273, 
                   'time': range(-252, 21) * 3, 
                   'ret': np.random.randn(273 * 3) * VOL / 252 ** .5, 
                   'Exp_Ret': np.random.randn(273 * 3) * VOL / 252 ** .5})

# Pivot on time and event_id.
df = df.set_index(['time', 'event_id']).unstack('event_id')

# Calculated return difference from t=0.
df_diff = df.ix[df.index >= 0, 'ret'] - df.loc[df.index >= 0, 'Exp_Ret']

# Calculate cumulative abnormal returns.
cum_returns = (1 + df_diff).cumprod() - 1

# Get 10 day abnormal returns.
>>> cum_returns.loc[10]
event_id
0   -0.014167
1   -0.172599
2   -0.032647
Name: 10, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like an elegant solution. Good to learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
((df+1.0) \
  .apply(lambda x: np.log(x),axis=1)\
  .rolling(365).sum() \
  .apply(lambda x: np.exp(x),axis=1)-1.0)
```

result is a rolling product.